# Count and group by in same query

Tags: mysql

`bid_count` is returning 1 ... how do I get it to return the correct bid count? I know that it's not returning the right count because I'm grouping by `user_id`. Can I alter the query so it counts also.

```
"SELECT id, bid, item_id, user_id, MAX(bid) AS max_bid, COUNT(bid) AS bid_count, bid_date
  FROM bids
  WHERE item_id = ? 
  GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY id DESC"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use unaggregated expressions in GROUP BY unless they are all same within the group.

If you want to return the record holding the counts by user_id, you should use an subquery to get the counts then join them to the result:

```
SELECT id, bid, item_id, user_id, bid_date, max_bid, bid_count
  FROM bids
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT user_id,MAX(bid) AS max_bid, COUNT(bid) AS bid_count
     FROM bids
    WHERE item_id = ? 
    GROUP BY user_id ) as group_table
ON bids.user_id = group_table.user_id
WHERE bids.item_id = ?
```

Comment: Ok ... I think I m just going to give up on this query. I wanted to run it every few seconds using javascript. And if it has a sub query I don't want it :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping it based on item_id. item_id should the one that has different bids.